# Add a pre-declared path to a filename argument (LPCSTR)

Tags: c++, function, path, arguments, filenames

I have a list of files I need to open in a certain function via a LPCSTR argument, but unfortunately they're located in certain folders (subdirectories of the main program root) with a very long path, and I don't want to type it in every time I want to pass the filenames.

To be more precise, I have the function D3DXCreateTextureFromFile() which asks for the filename, and for example, I have the files *a.png*, *b.png*, *c.png* located in the "...\Materials\Textures\Textures_For_This\Textures_For_That\More_Specific_Texture_Location\" subdirectory of the main program. How can I register this path and add it to the filename argument in a lean and mean way?

Like some sort of this:

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(bla, **DECLARED_DIR** + a.png, bla)
//same for b.png, c.png
```

Or even a subfunction that unifies the path and the filename:

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(bla, UnifyText(DECLARED_DIR, a.png), bla)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, easiest to make a function to combine the directory with the filename and include separator if required.  Because you want to pass this as an argument, you want to avoid allocating a string and having to clean it up...  So use the C++ `string` class.

I generally do something like this:

```
string TexturePath( LPCSTR filename = NULL )
{
    if( filename == NULL ) return string(TEXTURE_DIR);
    return string(TEXTURE_DIR) + "\" + filename;
}
```

Of course, you'll be relying on that string being implicitly cast to LPCSTR later.  If you want to be more explicit then do the (slightly ugly) call to `string::c_str()`:

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(bla, TexturePath("a.png").c_str(), bla)
```

*[Edit]*

Another way, if you are doing this single-threaded, is to use a static buffer:

```
LPCSTR TexturePath( LPCSTR filename = NULL )
{
    static char pathBuf[MAX_PATH];
    if( filename == NULL ) return TEXTURE_DIR;
    sprintf( pathBuf, "%s\\%s", TEXTURE_DIR, filename );
    return pathBuf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :L Finally a string combining system that works for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
    String main_dir="C:\\\Materials\\Textures\\Textures_For_This\\Textures_For_That\\More_Specific_Texture_Location\\";
    String files[]={"a.png","b.png","c.png"};
    String fullpath=main_dir;
    fullpath+=files[0];

    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(bla, fullpath.c_str(), bla);
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot too! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++ why not use a stringstream to concatenate the 2 strings together and then call .c_str() on the resulting string. Or you can use the c-style, strcat into a large enough buffer.